# How can I lock an individual cell in Excel with multiple passwords?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on building a new worksheet for multiple users that will serve as a checklist for our company. The goal is to introduce accountability at an individual and group level.

Our thought is to have each user capable of editing certain cells within the worksheet to "sign off" on each job done in the checklist. This group has a tendency to cover each other and say things are done without them actually being done, however (high school students), so we would like to include a user-specific password that will allow us to see who checked off on each item, instead of just covering their bases and entering initials for anyone.

The second level of this idea is to have a 4-digit number be assigned (perhaps using `InStr`?) to automatically add their initials. I.e., I enter 9999 into a cell, and my initials AB are what comes out.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If they already make entries for other members of the group, what would prevent them from also sharing their passwords?

Comment: Could add some form of user/change logging to the mix so you know what user did what.

Comment: Great question from Tim, but if I were to guess, the fear of being the one who check an item off that hasn't been completed, would stop them from sharing pw, but I don't know.  I also agree with Nick, it gets more complex by the fact that this will be done using VBA only.

Comment: When changes are made, are they big changes or is it just ticking a box (or a couple) and signing your name etc?

Answer (score 1):

I did a similar thing for an internship this past summer, and the way I went about it was somewhat complex, so I will try to give you the short answer.

1. Create a new hidden sheet, where to store passwords and initials of the individuals
2. Because high school students will probably attempt to un-hide the password sheet, I would hide the ribbon completely, but that is just precautionary.
3. Then, if you aren't interested in creating a top most modal-form, I would create a simple initial/password box that appears on the start-up of the Excel spreadsheet, and then if the initials and password combo is correct, store the initial's into a public variable, and when an item has been changed on the sheet (Use the event), have the initials be written to the proper cells.

If you need a more detailed answer, or want some example code, or anything else, please feel free to message me or email me.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You can also password protect the hidden sheet

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention that, thanks for noticing my mistake there.

Comment: You could also hash the passwords